# BreadcrumbList with "empty" level

Tags: google-search, schema.org, breadcrumbs, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

What is the proper way to annotate a breadcrumb with Schema.org annotations, if I want to skip the first level of a URL?

Example:

URL:

```
/it/songs/wish-you-were-here
```

The result on Google:

> example.com > IT > Songs > Wish You Were Here

As the first level is just the language indicator, my ideal result would rather be:

> example.com > Songs > Wish You Were Here

but I could also live with

> example.com/it > Songs > Wish You Were Here

**Is there any way to achieve this result?** I would rather not play around too much, as it takes time to propagate the changes.

The annotation:

```json
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement": [{
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "item": {
        "@id": "http://example.com/it",
        "name": "IT"
      }
    },{
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 2,
      "item": {
        "@id": "http://example.com/it/songs",
        "name": "Songs"
      }
    },{
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 3,
      "item": {
        "@id": "http://example.com/it/songs/wish-you-were-here",
        "name": "Wish you Were Here"
      }
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn’t document this on their [Breadcrumbs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs) page, so it’s not clear how this can be controlled (if at all). Not all of their features can be controlled with structured data.

Specifying the canonical URL of the homepage (i.e., including the language tag as first path segment) as first crumb seems to make sense. It signals that it’s *one* crumb, so if Google Search displays it as two crumbs, they seem to ignore the structured data in that regard. If that’s the case, you could try two things:

- Provide a `WebSite` item, giving the canonical URL for your site (i.e., the homepage) with `url`. (Like in the [example for the Sitelinks Searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox#example).)

  ```json
  {
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "https://example.com/it"
  }
  ```
- Omit the crumb for the homepage. (All of Google’s [examples](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs#use_cases) omit it.)

  ```json
  {
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "item": {
      "@id": "http://example.com/it/songs",
      "name": "Songs"
    }
  }
  ```

(I would try the first one first. It’s typically a good idea to have a `WebSite` item anyway.)

---

#### About your JSON-LD

Note that you are not using absolute URLs in your `@id` values.

If the snippet is included in the page at `http://example.com/it/songs/wish-you-were-here`, the `@id` for that page in the breadcrumbs would be `http://example.com/it/songs/example.com/it/songs/wish-you-were-here`, which is likely not what you want.

So either use `/it/songs/wish-you-were-here` or `http://example.com/it/songs/wish-you-were-here`.

(If this was not just an error in your question, you might want to fix it first and wait some time, to check if that changes how Google Search displays your breadcrumbs.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes, the lack of documentation is a problem. That's why I preferred to ask here if somebody already tried some of the options you propose. Before messing something up :) You are right, http was missing, corrected it now.

Comment: I did some test, apparently by not specifying the first block, as you suggest, I managed to obtain the desired result